# Azure analysis service connection using Service principal not working

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adomd.net, azure-analysis-services

I am trying to connect to Azure Analysis services using ADOMD and authenticated using a Service principal. So I have done following:

1. Create app in AAD.
2. Granted the app (Service principal) read permission on the Azure Analysis service.

Below is my code to connect to Azure Analysis service.

```
            var clientId = "******";
            var clientSecret = "*****";
            var domain = "****.onmicrosoft.com";
            var ssasUrl = "northeurope.asazure.windows.net";
            var token = await TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(domain, $"https://{ssasUrl}", clientId, clientSecret);

            var connectionString = $"Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=asazure://{ssasUrl}/{modelname};Initial Catalog= adventureworks;User ID=;Password={token};Persist Security Info=True;Impersonation Level=Impersonate";
            var ssasConnection = new AdomdConnection(connectionString);
            ssasConnection.Open();
            var query = @"Evaluate TOPN(10,Customer,Customer[Customer Id],1)";
            var cmd = new AdomdCommand(query)
            {
                Connection = ssasConnection
            };
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader())
            {
                string value = reader.ReadOuterXml();
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
```

I am able to get a valid access token, but I get following error when trying to open the connection:

**AdomdErrorResponseException: Either the user, 'app:xxxxxxx@xxxxxx', does not have access to the 'adventureworks' database, or the database does not exist.**

**Additional info:** :

1. I have verified that permissions (Reader & also tried with contribute) are given to Service principal to Azure analysis Service thru the Azure portal.
2. I have tried same code with service account (username & password) and it works.
3. If I remove "Initial Catalog= adventureworks" from the connection string then my connection will succeed. But I do not see why Analysis services permission is not propagated to the model.

**Resolution:**

Silly that I got the resolution by myself just after posting this. The point no 3 above gave me a clue.Granting permission on the Azure analysis services through the portal does not propagate to the model for the Service principals (Azuire AD apps).

Steps:

1. Open the Azure analysis service in Sql server Mgmt Studio.
2. In the target model, go to **Roles**.
3. Add the service principal into required role with permission. Service principal is added in below format:

   app:[appid]@[tenantid]

example : app:8249E22B-CFF9-440C-AF27-60064A5743CE@86F119BE-D703-49E2-8B5F-72392615BB97

Comment: According to the error log, it seems your service principal does not have permission to access your sql.  You should give it `database roles`. If it needs access other Azure resources, it needs `Owner` or `Contributor` role.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly that I got the resolution by myself just after posting this. The point no 3 above gave me a clue.Granting permission on the Azure analysis services through the portal does not propagate to the model for the Service principals (Azure AD apps).

Steps:

1. Open the Azure analysis service in Sql server Mgmt Studio.
2. In the target model, go to **Roles**.
3. Add the service principal into required role with permission. Service principal is added in below format:

   app:[appid]@[tenantid]

example : app:8249E22B-CFF9-440C-AF27-60064A5743CE@86F119BE-D703-49E2-8B5F-72392615BB97

I have blogged my whole experience here:https://unnieayilliath.com/2017/11/12/connecting-to-azure-analysis-services-using-adomd/

Comment: Awesome mate this was the last piece of the puzzle in my journey of discovery! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555021/use-automation-runas-service-principal-to-connect-to-azure-analysis-services-and/48576535?noredirect=1#comment84149886_48576535

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Glad it helped !

Comment: I'm just revisiting this now, but I'm trying to grant an Azure Automation RunAs account (which I think is a service principal???) access to SQL Azure. When I try to add `app:<appid>@tenantid` to a windows group from the CLI I get `The URI 'app:d23.......@a16...' is not valid since it is not based on 'https://graph.windows.net/a16...`

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-manage-users#user-permissions).

You need give the service principal `Owner` or `Contributor` role.

You could do it on Azure Portal. `<your subscription>--><Access Control>--><Add>`.

[image]

More information about this please refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role).

Comment: Maybe I should post my resolution (which I have updated in the question as a section) as an answer myself. I got it resolved by opening the Database in SSMS and adding Service principle to a reader role. Just granting permission to Service principal in azure portal does not work. Thanks for your answer tho

Comment: @Unnie If you only want to access SQL, you only need database role. If you want to other resources, you need `owner` role. Hope this help.

Comment: To process a cube you definitely need to explicitly give the app access.