# Use Automation RunAs service principal to connect to Azure Analysis Services and process

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-analysis-services

### TL;DR

In summary the steps are:

1. Use the correct code (the last code in this post)
2. Manually add your app id in SSMS as either a server administrator or a database administrator

and then you can process an Azure Analysis Services cube from an Azure Automation Account without needing to create another seperate service account

### Actual Question:

I am trying to process an Azure Analysis Services cube using the Azure Automation RunAs Service Principal. This is run within an Azure automation account

This code

```
#Get the existing AzureRunAsConnection connection
$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection

# Login with service principal account
Login-AzureRMAccount 
    -ServicePrincipal 
    -Tenant $Conn.TenantID 
    -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID 
    -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint

# Process cube
Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -databasename "DB" -server "Server" -RefreshType "Full"
```

Results in

> > Authentication failed: User ID and Password are required when user interface is not 
> >     available.

My understanding is that when you create an Azure Automation Account, it also creates a 'RunAs' account, which in turn creates a service principal account. (Although the doco seems a bit light on)

I have tried finding this principal account in Azure AD and adding it to SSAS Admins in the Azure portal, but I can't find the actual account. Do service principals actually appear as accounts?

The code below works fine, but it uses a pre saved credential but I don't want to have to manage yet another account.

```
# Purpose: Run a full process the SSAS cube
$AzureCred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "MyCredential"

Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $AzureCred | Out-Null
Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -databasename "MyDB" -server "MyServer" -RefreshType "Full" -Credential $AzureCred
```

### Update 1

I have also tried manually adding these in the SSMS membership area (after looking up the guids in the *RunAs Account* area in the automation account):

```
app:applicationid@tenantid

obj:serviceprincipalobjectid@tenantid
```

and I get the same error message.

I also ran the script with a non-admin user and got

> > The "zzz" database does not exist on the server.

So it would appear my issue is *authentication*, not authorisation. In other words it's not that I don't access, it's that I can't log in. I'm thinking based on that error, that `-credential` is not optional when calling `Invoke-ProcessAsDatabase` against Azure Analysis services

Also, I note that for the `-credential` option, the help says

> > If no credentials are specified, the default Windows account of the user running the script is assume

Given that Azure Analysis Services appears to only be able to use SQL credentials when connecting to a data source (no kind of AD credentials), I can only surmise that Azure Analysis Services is unable to use any kind of Azure Ad authentication for internal processes.

The annoying thing is that this isn't stated anywhere.

### Update 2

So I did not read the link carefully enough. The code that works is mostly on the site posted by both answerers [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/automation-of-azure-analysis-services-with-service-principals-and-powershell/). To pre authenicate to Azure Analysis Server you need to use `Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount` (The linked blog uses `Login-AzureAsAccount` but I couldn't get it working and couldn't find doco). You need to install powershell module "Azure.AnalysisServices" to use this.

```
$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount -RolloutEnvironment "australiasoutheast.asazure.windows.net" -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint
Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -databasename "MYDB" -server "MyServerEndpoint" -RefreshType "Full"
```

You can use the RunAs account with this, and afterwards you don't need to use `-credential`

So.. this actually works and logs in without needing a seperate credential, but now it doesn't have access to the database. Instead of a login error, I get

> The "ZZZZ" database does not exist on the server.

I would appear that the RunAs account has access to the server but not the database and I can't work out to find it to give it access.

### Update 3:

This is a more direct guide on how to give the app access to the model so it can be built:

[Azure analysis service connection using Service principal not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47160639/azure-analysis-service-connection-using-service-principal-not-working)

Note you can't add in the Azure portal as it won't find it. Add it "manually" in SSMS and it will work, and it will also appear in the Azure Portal as an admin

It all works now.

### Update 4:

This has become a handy spot to store my discoveries around authenticating through MSI

Although this question is solved, no I want to connect to SQL Azure from something else using MSI security. No connection string supports this - none of the authentication methods in any connection string support MSI authentication. I did find this interesting link which implies you *can* create a connection string that supports authentication as MSI:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi

The bit of code of interest is:

```
az webapp config connection-string set 
--resource-group myResourceGroup 
--name <app name> 
--settings MyDbConnection='Server=tcp:<server_name>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<db_name>;' 
--connection-string-type SQLAzure
```

I can't find any reference to the parameter `--connection-string-type`. But it looks like you simply exclude the authentication piece altogether.

Comment: In your example 1, it seems not your login Azure `Login-AzureRMAccount` get the error log. Based on my knowledge, `Invoke-ProcessASDatabase` is not a Azure Power Shell cmdlet. In fact, you no need to login your Azure subscription. Only `Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -databasename "MyDB" -server "MyServer" -RefreshType "Full" -Credential $AzureCred` should works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Certainly this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/powershell/invoke-processasdatabase has "Azure Analysis Services" ticked for the cmdlet for what it's worth. I'm not sure what you mean about `Login-AzureRMAccount`. That's my attempt to pre-authenticate so that `Invoke-ProcessASDatabase` works without a credential. Yes if I supply a credential it works, but I want to use the RunAs credential. If I can't, then what is the point of it.

Comment: `Login-AzureRMAccount` is to login Azure subscription. Azure cmdlet like `Get-AzureRmVM` need you login firstly. `Invoke-ProcessASDatabase` is not a Azure cmdlet. Azure runbook likes a VM in cloud that you could execute Power Shell cmdlet.

Comment: In fact, Azure does not your SQL credential, so you need use `$-Credential $AzureCred` The credential is your sql credential not your Azure account credential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example 1, it seems not your login Azure `Login-AzureRMAccount` get the error log. Based on my knowledge, `Invoke-ProcessASDatabase` is not a Azure Power Shell cmdlet. In fact, you no need to login your Azure subscription. Only `Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -databasename "MyDB" -server "MyServer" -RefreshType "Full" -Credential $AzureCred` should works for you.

> Yes if I supply a credential it works, but I want to use the RunAs
>   credential. If I can't, then what is the point of it.

`RunAs credential` only works for login your Azure subscription, it does not stores credential for your SQL. In your scenario, you could store your SQL credential in runbook PSCredential, like your example2. In fact, in your example, you could remove `Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $AzureCred | Out-Null`.

Update:

You should use following script in runbook.

```
$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection 
Login-AzureASAccount -RolloutEnvironment "southcentralus.asazure.windows.net" -ServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint -TenantId $Conn.TenantID 
Invoke-ProcessTable -Server "asazure://southcentralus.asazure.windows.net/myserver" -TableName "MyTable" -Database "MyDb" -RefreshType "Full"
```

More information about this please check this [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/automation-of-azure-analysis-services-with-service-principals-and-powershell/).

Comment: For the purposes of kicking off a cube process, Azure Analysis Services doesn't use a SQL Logins. Client access to the front end of Azure Analysis Services is _only_ AD. To put it another way,  I need to connect to AAS to kick of a build process, and I can only authenticate as an AD user. So... if the Azure Automation Account has created a service principal (which is apparently conceptually like a service account on-prem), then why can't I even _find_ that account, let alone use it to connect to AAS?

Comment: What I want to do is 1. Find the automatically created Azure Automation Account service principal, and assign that process rights in the AAS model. I can't do this because I can't find it!. 2. Now I want to use that same service principal in my PS script. I don't think the cmdlet supports that but if I could get the service principal as a PSCredential, all would be solved

Comment: Basically I want to use the tried and tested service account approach where the process (Azure Automation) runs under a service principal and as long as that principal is granted access to the target, everything works without having to repeat passwords everywhere.

Comment: Yes, you could find this service principal, firstly find application id. https://imgur.com/a/axjvd Then find it on Azure AD blade. https://imgur.com/a/f8jPh

Comment: Hi, what you want is this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/automation-of-azure-analysis-services-with-service-principals-and-powershell/)?  But it seems if you want to login, you should use `Login-AzureAsAccount ` not `Login-AzureRMAccount`, they are different.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the AD blade so I'm relegated to searching for it in the various add tools (in SSMS, SSDT and the Analysis Services Admin Designator). I can't find the service principal by name by application id, or by service principal object id. This would be a lot easier if I had access.

Comment: I have been through that link a few times. The service principal doesn't appear when searching in the role membership part. Do you mind if we have a quick chat?

Comment: The other thing with that link is it requires a password - I don't know the password! Someone else created the principal not me! Besides, I don't want to have hard code a password if the process is already running under that usert

Comment: Maybe the service account analogy just doesn't work in Azure... which is kinda ludicrous

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164381/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-nick-mcdermaid).

Answer (score 1):

Per the official documentation:

> Once the service principal is created, its application ID can be assigned permissions in the Azure Analysis Services server or model roles using the following syntax. The example below adds a service principal to the server administrators group in SSMS.

I didn't see the use of Run-as option, i'd recommend checking this [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/automation-of-azure-analysis-services-with-service-principals-and-powershell/)

It also contains information about **storing credentials in azure automation**, this will help you in not hard writing credentials in the code.

Comment: Thanks. I did see that blog but the problem is I cannot find the service principal in any search box (SSMS, SSDT or the Azure portal). I went into the automation account and clicked "runas accounts" and it gave me a whole lot of details on it, including a display name, which I assume is what I need to search on in active directory. Anyway I manually entered the hexadecimal strings as indicated in the blog and retried and got the same error. I am currently storing credentials in azure automation but this is not satisfactory because I have to maintain a password in here

Comment: In addition to this, I couldn't get Azure to use any authentication to the source SQL Azure database except SQL Authentication. So it's really disappointing coming from on-prem where everything runs under service accounts (except for dreaded double hop) then moving to Azure where I have to go back to the old days of storing credentials and needing to create separate SQL Users

Comment: Have you had experience using service principal accounts? my automation account is called `xydevauto01`. The "Azure Active Directory Application" display name is `xydevauto01_qwoisaldadwlwahlahjwlad` and that's what I'm searching for. I also tried adding the "service principal object id" like this: `obj:serviceprincipalobjectid@tenantid` and same error. I'm starting to think from that error message that the `-credential` option is _not_ optional for `Invoke-ProcessASDatabase` in Azure. So... is it possible to get a pscredential object out of the RunAs connection?
 (yes I did google it!)

Comment: The other reason I didn't get too far with that link is that the example generates a credential from user/password, and of course I don't know the runas service principal password, nor do I want to have to save it as a credential - that defeats the purpose if a service account. It's like when you install SQL Server and it uses virtual accounts - I should have to know the password for the virtual account, I should just be able to assign rights to the virtual account. (I know this isn't best practice for on-prem, but why generate a runas service principal if it just discarded?)